# Ouput escaped sequences on Windows

Tags: go, ascii, stdin

Is there something like [colorama](https://github.com/tartley/colorama) (python) for golang? Not just to output color, but to be able to just write `print("\033[1;32mMy text in green\033[0m")` and get the colored text?

I pipe a string from a program (say `git log --color=always`) which output escaped sequences, and I want to be able to output it with the colors too.

```
$ git log --color=always | go run prog.go
```

How can I make the escaped sequences work? (I get these kinds of thing `?[1;32` where the color was supposed to be set).

Is there no better solution than parsing the string and use [color](https://github.com/fatih/color) for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/shiena/ansicolor did what I needed. Almost perfect.

```
writer := ansicolor.NewAnsiColorWriter(os.Stdout)
fmt.Fprint(writer, "\033[1;32mMy text in green\033[0m")
# that works!
```